# Meter en un select FOREACH un valor null

Tags: php, select

Buenas como puedo meter aquí que también pueda seleccionar un "ninguno" con value "null"....

```
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" name="etiqueta">
  <?php
   $etiqueta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM etiqueta");
   foreach ($etiqueta as $eti){
  ?>
  <option value='<?php echo $eti['etiqueta_id']; ?>' <?php  if(trim($eti['etiqueta_id'])==$res['etiqueta_id']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>><?php echo $eti['etiqueta']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Probe de este modo, pero no funciona bien, directamente no hace el update la consulta de ese campo.

```
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" 

name="etiqueta">
  <option value=''>Ninguna</option>
  <?php
   $etiqueta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM etiqueta");
   foreach ($etiqueta as $eti){
  ?>
  <option value='<?php echo $eti['etiqueta_id']; ?>' <?php  
 if(trim($eti['etiqueta_id'])==$res['etiqueta_id']){ ?> selected <?
 php } ?>><?php echo $eti['etiqueta']; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: eso ya va en tu logica en metodo sea POST o GET  donde recibes los parametros...validas si recibes algo y sino lo colocas por defecto null

Comment: Es decir, lo estaba haciendo bien, pero tengo que hacer una condición de que si llega vacio sea "null" @DiegoAvila

Comment: exacto..debes validar si trae un valor o no

Comment: Vale vale, entiendo. Lo pongo en marcha pues, muchas gracias!

Comment: perdona, tengo una duda. Ya hago un If para saber si la propiedad lleva una foto o no, tiene que ser con un IF, si es así como lo puedo hacer, voy a añadir el codigo de actualizar @DiegoAvila

Comment: ya te agregue mi respuesta pruebalo..!!

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer algo asi:

```
<form action="mi_archivo.php" method="POST">
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" required>
      <option value=''>Ninguna</option>
      <?php
       $etiqueta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM etiqueta");
       foreach ($etiqueta as $eti){
      ?>
      <option value='<?php echo $eti['etiqueta_id']; ?>' <?php  if(trim($eti['etiqueta_id'])==$res['etiqueta_id']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>><?php echo $eti['etiqueta']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
     </select>
<input type="submit" value="ACEPTAR">
</form>
```

**mi_archivo.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['etiqueta'])) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (etiqueta)VALUES ('$_POST['etiqueta']')";
}else{
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tabla (etiqueta)VALUES (NULL)";
}
...
..
?>
```

si te fijas mediante una condición le asigno directamente al query el valor deseado o recibido..!!

algo asi podrias hacerlo, espero te sirva..!!

Comment: Eso lo puedo hacer justo donde recibo ese campo POST no, para luego hacer los insert etc...

Comment: si en efecto luego puedes hacer el insert con el valor de la seleccion sea null o lo que se escogio..!!

Comment: Yo lo que e hecho es poner donde recibo `$seleccion =$_POST['etiqueta'];` he puesto lo que me has pasado y en el insert inserto `$seleccion` pero sigue pasando lo mismo @Diego Avila

Comment: y que se inserta o que error genera..?

Comment: no creo que puedas por como te traes los datos.
Ese fore each te trae los valores de tu base de datos y como ella no tiene ese "null" no lo podras setear como quieres...

Comment: Se queda tal como estaba, si tenia un value='8' por ejemplo se queda en ese

Comment: revisa mi respuesta a ver si te soluciona el problema @Miguel

Comment: lo acabo de hacer @JuanOrtiz y me sucede lo mismo, hace caso omiso a esa opción

Comment: Lo que e hecho es poner un "0" en lugar de un "null" y asi de ese modo si que lo reconoce

Comment: ya edito mi respuesta..checalo..!!

Comment: podrias crear un query en cada caso si trae un valor o no..!!

Comment: ya edite la respuesta, prueba y me dices.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="mi_archivo.php" method="POST">
<select id="select2-4" value="" class="form-control" name="etiqueta" required>

      <?php
       $etiqueta = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM etiqueta");
       foreach ($etiqueta as $eti){
    echo '<option value="NULL" selected="selected" >Select a topic</option>';
```

?>

```
      <option value='<?php echo $eti['etiqueta_id']; ?>' <?php  if(trim($eti['etiqueta_id'])==$res['etiqueta_id']){ ?> selected <?php } ?>><?php echo $eti['etiqueta']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
     </select>
<input type="submit" value="ACEPTAR">
</form>
```

solo use selected en el option para obligar a mostrar esa en la primera opcion